# Django Admin Forms with additional fields in ManyToMany relations

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

I have 2 Entities with a ManyToMany Relation and some additional fields, here you can find an example diagram:

[image]

I created all models following the documentation and everything works, but I would also manage MTM relations using django admin without use another form to create a new "WheelsCar" row that links togheter a car and a wheel. Is it possible? How?

Admin use case:

1. I click on add new Car
2. I select one of the wheels, filling the additional fields (position, holes...)
3. Iterate step 2
4. Save a New Car

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it, I have to use Inline Fields!

Doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models